# Creating an If statement for an entire array

Tags: arrays, if-statement

So here is my situation. I'm new to programming and I've just started making a very, very basic platform game. And I mean literally a game with platforms.

I've got my character in and jumping about and I've created my platforms as an array. This was so that I could put them all side by side at the bottom. Now there is other ways I can do this to get round the problem but I wanted to find out how to do it for an array.

So I've got my character falling with this

```
kirby.yVelocity += 1.0f
```

Which is all fine but I want his yVelocity to go to 0.0f when he hits any of the platforms in the array.

So I tried this piece of code

```
if (plat[i].drawRect.Intersects(kirby.drawRect))
{
kirby.yVelocity = 0.0f
}
```

which I thought would work but it gives me an error for the [i] saying that it isn't applicable in this context.

few notes:

kirby is my character name, drawRect is the definition for Rectangle, plat is my Platform array which consists of 13 platforms.

Thanks to anyone who can help

---

Update

The problem is any variation of plat.drawRect or plat[i].drawRect don't work. Here is all my code relating to the platform arrays.

```
 struct Platform
    {
        public Texture2D txr;
        public Rectangle drawRect;
    }

Platform[] plat;

   plat = new Platform[13];
           for (int i = 0; i < plat.Length; i++)
           {
               plat[i].txr = Content.Load<Texture2D>("platform");
               plat[i].drawRect = new Rectangle(i * plat[i].txr.Width, 460, plat[i].txr.Width, plat[i].txr.Height);`
           }

 for (int i = 0; i < plat.Length; i++)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(plat[i].txr, plat[i].drawRect, Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to add a for loop, to loop over the platforms. Maybe like this:

```
for(Platform : plat){
    if (platform.drawRect.Intersects(kirby.drawRect)){
        kirby.yVelocity = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Here, I'm assuming you're using Java and `Platform` is the class of your plat-array, which has class `List<Platform>`.

Comment: Have added an addition to my question in response to you Gijs

Comment: Gandeh, if plat[i] doesn't work anywhere, is the second part of your code working at all?

Comment: Yes the plat[i] works in the sense that it creates the Platforms in a line along the bottom as they are supposed to appear. I only run into trouble when I try to code a If statement to create a collision rule. I just need to figure out how you refer to the 'Rectangles' for all the array items. Because what I basically want to do in an If statement is - If the character ever intersects with a Platform rectangle then change characters yVelocity to 0.0f . But as I say I can't get any variation of plat[i].drawRect to work.

Comment: for the first line it underlines Platform : plat with three individual underlines and says in order "Only assignment, call, incremenet, dcrement and new object expression can be used as a statement" - "; expected" - "; expected".    And then it underlines in the second line platform and says "the name 'platform' does not exist in the current context.  The latter could be because my structure is called Platform but it is abbreviated in the array with this line of code - Platform[] plat;